# "err:seh:setup_exception stack overflow" when compiling constexpr code in MSVC

Tags: c++, constexpr

Compiling the following code ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/rsLgBm)):

```
constexpr bool f(const char *&s) {
  do {
    ++s;
  } while (*s);
  return true;
}

constexpr bool g(const char *s) {
  return f(s);
}

int main() {
  static_assert(g("x"), "");
}
```

gives this error on MSVC:

```
err:seh:setup_exception stack overflow 1552 bytes in thread 0058 eip 000000007b48dad8 esp 0000000000131000 stack 0x130000-0x131000-0x1130000
```

while other compilers (GCC and Clang) happily accept it.

Why doesn't this code compile on MSVC and how can I fix it?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the fact that you're incrementing the pointer *before* doing the null check. That would invoke undefined behavior on an empty string. I don't know why it's an issue here. Altering your code in Godbolt to check before incrementing doesn't seem to fix the issue, either.

Comment: Pretty clearly a bug. Even if that code was invalid, this is not the message MSVC should give you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to compile by removing the reference qualifier from the function signature ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/eYquBd)):

```
constexpr bool f(const char *s) {//No longer passes a pointer by reference
  while(*s) { //This avoids undefined behavior when the passed string is empty
    ++s;
  }
  return true;
}

constexpr bool g(const char *s) {
  return f(s);
}

int main() {
  static_assert(g("x"), "");
}
```

I don't know why passing the pointer by reference causes this error, though, and I maintain that this is probably a bug in MSVC's compiler. You should post the bug to their [bug tracking forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).